# How to create circles around a ellipse shape dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to create a circle (div tag) around an ellipse shape dynamically using React (Next Js) and Tailwind CSS as the styling. How to? I have created code like the following but the parent position is not right in the middle

// parent component

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import ChildDiv from "./components/ChildDiv";

const ParentDiv: React.FC = () => {
  const totalParticipants: number = 25;
  const parentDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [childDivs, setChildDivs] = useState<Array<{ x: number; y: number }>>(
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const div: number = 360 / totalParticipants;
    const radiusX: number = 320;
    const radiusY: number = 195;

    const offsetToParentCenter: number = parentDivRef.current
      ? parentDivRef.current.offsetWidth / 2
      : 0;

    const totalOffsetX: number = 40;
    const totalOffsetY: number = 40;

    const childDivsArray: Array<{ x: number; y: number }> = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= totalParticipants; i++) {
      const y: number = Math.sin((div * i * Math.PI) / 180) * radiusY;
      const x: number = Math.cos((div * i * Math.PI) / 180) * radiusX;
      childDivsArray.push({ x: x + totalOffsetX, y: y + totalOffsetY });
    }

    setChildDivs(childDivsArray);
  }, [totalParticipants]);

  return (
    <div className="bg-yellow-400 flex h-full justify-center items-center">
      <div
        id="parentdiv"
        ref={parentDivRef}
        className="relative w-80 h-40 bg-red-500 rounded-full m-40 "
      >
        {childDivs.map((child, index) => (
          <ChildDiv key={index} x={child.x} y={child.y} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentDiv;
```

// Child Component

```
const ChildDiv: React.FC<{ x: number; y: number }> = ({ x, y }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="absolute h-10 w-10 bg-blue-500 rounded-full"
      style={{ top: `${y}px`, left: `${x}px` }}
    ></div>
  );
};
export default ChildDiv;
```

The result of the code is like this
[result from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4frba.png)

I want the red shape (Parent) to be right in the middle. How to?